# Remove broken Visual Studio 2017 Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently unistalled MonoGame but after doing so the templates still remained. I did a search from the explorer and removed the templates from the AppData folder. This didnt completely remove them becuse now I'm left with broken templates in the "New Project" Window in Visual Studio. When I try to create a project with them it says something like "Template doesnt exist, please repair the file" but it gives me no option to remove the broken template from the list. How would I do this?

Comment: Look in the registry for remnants of the templates.

Comment: @DavidPostill Can you please elaborate? :)

Comment: No as I don't have MonoGames or Visual Studio installed. Typically information about program configurations (templates) is stored in the registry. See [Registering Project and Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165750.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Thanks for your help but there were no remnants of the templates in the registry. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VinnieH01's method is like using a machine gun to kill a fly.

You should rather delete only the **ProjectTemplatesCache** folder in a whole, which will get rid of outdated templates and nothing else.

The full path would be:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version_and_optional_ID>\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

Comment: Havent tried it but it should work so I'm accepting this answer instead of mine

Comment: Similar answer at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789095/how-can-i-delete-bad-visual-studio-templates).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by clearing the Visual Studio Cache, to do this you remove the contents of the following folder:

**"C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio".**

Just remember to save your CurrentSettings file since all of your settings will be lost.